# Why is ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory throwing access denied here?

Tags: c#, uwp, zip

I'm suffering from a file access problem.

The main problem is I can't write a ZipFile in a **folder which is acquired by the Folder Picker.**

While I've been working on this project, until I encountered this ZipFile problem, I did lots of jobs associated with creating files, with deleting files, with creating folders in that folder. It doesn't seem to matter for this problem.

As [the file-access documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#locations-uwp-apps-can-access) says, I have access permission on a folder which is chosen by the user when using the folder picker.

But I can't create this ZipFile in that folder. Below are my source and the exception.

```
string zipfPath = folder.Path + @"\" + i.ToString() + ".zip";
await folder.CreateFolderAsync("DADADAD");
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(folder.Path + @"/DADADAD", zipfPath);
```

[image: denied]

Why I can't access that folder with `ZipFile.Create(Path string)`?  Are there additional requirements when using UWP?   Am I just my misusing `ZipFile.Create` perhaps?

#### Edit

Exception Message is following
**System.UnauthorizedAccessException:** 'Access to the Path 'C:\Users\yohan\Desktop\새 폴더 (2)\1.zip' is denied'.

Comment: can you try to run you program as administrator? 
(or by running visual studio as admin, or the file )

Comment: @OrYaacov I tried to run my visual studio as admin, but the result was same as my post.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

Comment: @LosPollosHermanos you can see my source code is similar with that link's answer. I don't think I did replace a directory to a file.

Comment: @HansPassant As link's says, in my source, folder <-- is StorageFolder object that is gained by Folder Picker. because I have Permission on that folder, I have no error "await folder.CreateFolderAsync("DADADAD");". but ZipFile 
Class behaves differently with docs.  I don't understand it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is correct: you don't have direct access to that folder. For now your best option is probably to create a ZipArchive, enumerate the folder via a [FolderQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.createfolderquery) and stream each file individually into a [ZipEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.createentry?view=netstandard-2.0).

More details:

Your access is granted via the StorageFolder returned by the file picker and needs to be used through that StorageFolder.

Quoting from the [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) documentation you linked and adding some emphasis for clarity:

> After you retrieve a StorageFolder that represents an app data
>   location, you can access files and folders in that location **by using
>   StorageFolder methods**.

Since the ZipFile doesn't use the StorageFolder methods it can't reach the target folder. The permissions are not attached to the Path passed to the ZipFile.

I discussed this in greater depth in my blog entry [Skip the path: stick to the StorageFile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/)

There is work being done to plumb the brokered access through the direct file system calls, but it's not yet complete. In current versions of Windows 10 you can use  [IStorageFolderHandleAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/desktop/api/windowsstoragecom/nn-windowsstoragecom-istoragefolderhandleaccess), [IStorageItemHandleAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/desktop/api/windowsstoragecom/nn-windowsstoragecom-istorageitemhandleaccess) or [CreateFile2FromApp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt846584) to get a native file HANDLE which you can use to create a System.IO.File object, but it won't work for .Net classes such as ZipFile which take a Path and open the file themselves.

Comment: very Thanks for clear answer. I read your blog and now I have a some clear understanding that why I can't use It. I will follow your suggestion(ZipArchive and ZipEntry), and I will read docs carefully from now.

Comment: @RobCaplan, Thank you for your post. If I use ZipArchive and ZipEntry as you have suggested, hidden files, folders, .URL files are not added to it as you can see in this sample. Any suggestions?
https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/ZipFile

Answer (score 4):

I implement with StorageFile, Stream, ZipArchive, ZipArchiveEntry, Stream Writer.
below is my short source for create zip file in a folder acquired by folder picker().
It works great. Rob Caplan, Thanks for your very clear explanation.

```
                StorageFile f = await folder.CreateFileAsync("test.zip");

                using (Stream s = (await f.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()))
                {
                    using (ZipArchive zz = new ZipArchive(s, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
                    {
                        ZipArchiveEntry read = zz.CreateEntry("scc.txt");
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(read.Open()))
                        {
                            await sw.WriteLineAsync("StackOverFlow");
                            await sw.WriteLineAsync("Thanks!");
                        }
                    }
                }
```